# What is meant by "place 4 inches apart on cookie tray"?

Tags: baking, cookies

Does this mean place some cookie dough every 4 inches (i.e. 4 inches center-to-center), or have a 4 inch gap between each cookie?

Comment: Wow how big are those cookie(How much is each ball of dough)? 4 inch buffer on every side? That's like a 8 inch diameter cookie.

Comment: Mom would only allow me one cookie at a time when I was a kid, so I would present her recipes for big cookies. Seriously though, I suspected it would refer to the gap so I made the size suggest it was center-to-center.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means to have a 4 inch gap between each cookie. Of course, if you use less dough per cookie, you can put them a bit closer together.

Normally, if you put cookie dough on the tray, the surface of the cookie won't be very big (perhaps an inch). So it would not make a very big difference if you would've placed the cookies 4 inches apart center-to-center. Just be careful during the first batch. If you see you have a lot of space between the finished cookies, you can put the dough closer together for the next batch (if you use the same amount of dough per cookie).